# Share generic views between models

Tags: django, django-views

Is there any way to share a generic view between different models? I have 5 models and all of them need a ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView and DeleteView so, instead of creating all these classes for those 5 models, I'd like to create just one of each type for them. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View that does many things is a bad idea. You can minimize or eliminate views classes by this way (haven't tried but you should be able to pass a model into view like this):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^model1/$',
        ListView.as_view(model=Model1),
        name='model1_list'
    ),
    url(
        r'^model2/$',
        ListView.as_view(model=Model2),
        name='model2_list'
    ),
]
```

The same principle with other views.